# Delete record from Contact list get BAD_ACCESS error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, addressbook

I want to delete a contact from addressBook. I use this code to delete a contact from contact list of device.

```
var recordId = ABRecordID(contact.contactId)
var newContact: ABRecordRef! = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(self.add?.adbk, recordId).takeRetainedValue()

var success: Bool = false

var error: Unmanaged<CFErrorRef>? = nil

success = ABAddressBookRemoveRecord(self.add?.adbk, newContact, &error)

println("Adbk addRecord successful? \(success) error \(error)")

createAddressBook()

if success {
    success = ABAddressBookSave(self.add?.adbk, &error)

    println("Adbk save successful? \(success) error \(error)")
}
```

But I don't understand why I get `BAD_ACCESS` error in run time. I stop the program and run again, the contact deleted successfuly. Also in my code the `SIGKill` signal is written. What should I have to do?

Comment: Isn't 'self.add?.adbk' returning an optional? This can be a reason for crashing.

Comment: Can you highlight the line where you get the crash at?

Comment: It crashes at the end of the method,not specific line.

Comment: You should declare `var error = NSError()`

Comment: I change my code to have not optional value, but I have error again. In my console is written "message sent to deallocated instance"

Comment: I test error=NSError but it returns compile error!